# Common websites displaying "Server's certificate is not trusted" on new Server 2012 R2 image

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

I've recently been tasked with migrating one of our company's web app servers from Server 2008 to Server 2012 R2. While on the new server and trying to download some apps to set it up I keep getting greeted by warning pages. In Chrome many of the trusted sites I visit normally (e.g. Any msdn, technet, or github page), it brings up the warning page "Your connection is not private" and the padlock in the address bar shows:

> "The identity of this website has not been verified.
>
> - Server's certificate is not trusted."

I might add my role is a developer, not network/server admin so there might be something obvious to others in such a role that I haven't learned yet.

From what I read in this [Microsoft post](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265983.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the trusted certificates should be updated automatically. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have an internet proxy configured on the new server? Without that the CRL validation is likely to fail and that could lead to cert issues.

Answer (score 0):

If a certificate was issued by an authority that is part of the Microsoft Trusted Root CA program, Windows should attempt to download the certificate of the CA in the chain - at the time they are needed. If the server is unable to download the certificate(s) in the chain or the feature is disallowed by policy, this will not work as expected.  You may also want to try using Internet Explorer to see if the auto-download works as expected.  You can get more information about certificate issues by enabling the CAPI2 event log.

You can also install the *required* root/issuing certificates in the appropriate stores yourself and not rely on this behavior.  (Note that you should not attempt to import all ~350 certificates as that would cause problems for your server.)

For Chrome, if the certificate is an EV certificate, additional restrictions apply.

Google Chrome Root Certificate Policy
http://dev.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/root-ca-policy

Current Microsoft Trusted Root CA list is published here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31634.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-participants.aspx

Microsoft Trusted Root CA deployment notices published here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31680.microsoft-trusted-root-certificate-program-updates.aspx